# MVC model evaluated as invalid because of some missing posted data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a View that is rendered with a hidden form and all the fields of a given entity model. At some point, via JavaScript, I enter the data in those fields and post the form.

On the controller I'm receiving the posted data on an instance of that Entity Model, except for one attribute only. Checking (with a watch) for the `Request.Form`, the attribute is just there with the correct name and a value.

What could be happening?

Here's some of the code:
(View)

```
<div id="dvHiddenFormularioPacientePesquisa" style="display:none;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ParticipacaoPaciente", "RealizacaoPesquisa", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmPacientePesquisa" }))
    {
        PacientePesquisa PacientePesquisa;
        if (Model.PacientePesquisa != null) { PacientePesquisa = Model.PacientePesquisa; } 
        else 
        { 
            PacientePesquisa = new PacientePesquisa();
            PacientePesquisa.IDPesquisa = Model.Pesquisa.IDPesquisa;
            PacientePesquisa.NRProntuario = Model.Paciente.NRProntuario;
        }

        @Html.HiddenFor(paciente => PacientePesquisa.IDPacientePesquisa)
        @Html.HiddenFor(paciente => PacientePesquisa.IDPesquisa)
        @Html.HiddenFor(paciente => PacientePesquisa.NRProntuario)
        @Html.HiddenFor(paciente => PacientePesquisa.CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa)
        @Html.HiddenFor(paciente => PacientePesquisa.IDMotivoExclusaoIndividuo)
        @Html.HiddenFor(paciente => PacientePesquisa.ObsMotivoExclusao)
    }
</div>
```

(JS action)

```
$('#PacientePesquisa_CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa').val('A'); //Situação do Paciente-Pesquisa: (A)tivo
$('#PacientePesquisa_IDMotivoExclusaoIndividuo').val('');
$('#PacientePesquisa_ObsMotivoExclusao').val('');
$('#frmPacientePesquisa').submit();
return true;
```

(Controller)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ParticipacaoPaciente(PacientePesquisa pacPesq)
{ 
    try
    {
        if (pacPesq.IDPacientePesquisa <= 0) 
        {
            pacPesq.IDUsuario = this.LoggedUser().IDUsuario;
            pacPesq.DataCriacao = DateTime.Now;
        }

        //Limpeza dos erros de validação prévios
        foreach (var modelValue in ModelState.Values)
        {
            modelValue.Errors.Clear();
        }
        //Re-validação do modelo
        ValidateModel(pacPesq); //<== Error here, due to pacPesq.CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa == null, when the posted data value for this attribute is "A"
```

EDIT:

(Entity definition of that field)

```
public string CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa { get; set; } /* "A" = Ativo / "E" = Excluído */
```

(Watch of "Request.Form")

```
Request.Form    
{
    PacientePesquisa.IDPacientePesquisa=0
    PacientePesquisa.IDPesquisa=1
    PacientePesquisa.NRProntuario=0000009903
    PacientePesquisa.CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa=A
    PacientePesquisa.IDMotivoExclusaoIndividuo=
    PacientePesquisa.ObsMotivoExclusao=
}   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection {System.Web.HttpValueCollection}
```

Comment: What CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa expects? Maybe the ModelBinder is miss matching the posted value with the expected value, then Its not getting binded!

Comment: @Fals editted the question to put some more info. Does not appear to be a data type problem...

Comment: Did you tried any other arbitrary string? Do you can see all others values into pacPesq method param?

Comment: @Fals, yes, all other parameters are binded acordingly to the values of the watch (except for the "CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa" attribute). On the controller method, before the model validation I'm assigning the value "A" (hard coded) and then, everything goes... Something is preventing this specific attribute to be binded as since the view's field is rendered with a Html helper using the entity itself, it's not the name of the attribute... As last effort, I will manually assign it's value from the Form.Request (Ugly!)

Comment: Well, try a different value for CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa and test it. Another thing that i saw, CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa has the longest property name in your model, and the only one that have not been assigned correcly, try to change this name as well!

Answer (score 0):

Upod seeing your form I've noticed that your create view is not using model as your strongly typed view instead it seems you are using custom model binder that's why when you post the form your controller doesn't bind your model from your view. There are two ways you can do if you still want to retain your current implementation.

**Number 1 Solution:**

***Assign each field from your form collections to your model class***

Example:

```
pacPesq.CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa=Request.Form["CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa"];
pacPesq.IDMotivoExclusaoIndividuo=Request.Form["IDMotivoExclusaoIndividuo"];
```

**Number 2 Solution: Use CustomModelBinder/Dynamic**

To use CustomModelBinder see this example: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASP-NET-MVC-Dynamic-Model-Binding.aspx

Comment: you're right that I'm not using a strongly typed view. Anyway, as I'm posting the correct object data, data binder should be able to correctly bind it (and in fact it is - for all the attributes except for specifically one of them). The key question here is: what's diffrerent or wrong with the attribute "CodSituacaoPacientePesquisa" that prevents it's value from being binded? (and as said, the value is correctly present on the Form.Request)